# Reading very large file numpy and retrieving only specific values

Tags: python

I have a really large file, over one million lines. It contains two columns, both integers. The second column isn't important so I can ignore it. What I want to do is to read the file and only retrieve all the values from the first column that are less than 20,000. However, I am having issues.

What I have thus far is but since the file is so large this will cause issues:

```
data = np.loadtxt("./muon.txt", usecols = (0))
for values in data:
   if values < 20,000:
     \\ store values to some array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's simple in numpy:

```
values = data[data < 20000]
```

`data < 20000` creates a boolean mask that's `True` where a value is less than 20,000 and `False` otherwise. When you then index `data` with that mask it only picks the values where the mask is `True`, thus giving exactly what you want.

Comment: Ty. Will the full code just be:

`data = np.loadtxt("./muon.txt", usecols = (0))`

`values = data[data < 20000]`

Comment: @Robin Yes, to get the values you want.